# Default WordML Unit Measurement ? pixel or point or inches

Tags: xml, openxml, docx, wordml

Please clarify the my doubt
WordML/DOCX Default Unit Measurement is pixel or point or EMU or inches.. ?

Comment: Follow up - http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml/ - "The main unit in OOXML is a twentieth of a point.". This does not apply to fonts.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is something called DXA. There are 1440 DXA per inch. 1 inch is 72 points. 1 DXA is 1/20th's of a point (20 DXA is 1 point). There is also something called EMU's (914400 EMUs is 1 inch, 12700 EMUs is 1pt).

Please don't ask me how I know this. Microsoft ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 9):

I created unit converted for openXML https://unit-converter-bcmmybn3dq-ez.a.run.app/

There also a table with formulas for all common office units.

[image]

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: https://unit-converter-bcmmybn3dq-ez.a.run.app/ use that please :)