# Convert Google slides EMU units to pixels - API

Tags: java, powerpoint, google-slides-api, google-slides

I am using Google API to get cropping, dimensions, and scaling information for the pictures which are present in a given google slide presentation. This information I intend to port and use in publishing these slides as webpages (HTML) or port the same content to Google docs (as the case may be).

The problem that I am facing is I am not clear how the EMU units map to pixels.

Based on trial and error calculation 9525 EMU seems to be 1 pixel.

But when I refer to

- https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/Unit
- https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml/
  I am getting 3750 EMU = 1 Pixel which is 1/2.54 of what it is practically appearing to be.

Interestingly the factor is 2.54 which is how many centimeters an inch is.

I think I can manage with the 9525 conversion factor, but it doesn't make sense, and I want to be sure I am on the right track.
Does anybody have some clarity on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/Unit):

> An English Metric Unit (EMU) is defined as 1/360,000 of a centimeter and thus there are 914,400 EMUs per inch, and 12,700 EMUs per point.

I'm guessing that they used the same units as CSS. In that case, you can find [on the official specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/CR-css-values-3-20190606/#reference-pixel) that 1 inch is equivalent to 96 pixels:

> The reference pixel is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm’s length. For a nominal arm’s length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm’s length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

From there the math is simple:

```
914,400 / 96 = 9525
```

Which is what you found experimentally.

### References

- [Unit (Google Slides API)](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/Unit)
- [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a defined amount of EMU per inch, as well as the amount of PX per inch so, depending on the image's density, the conversion factor is different. More info: [OpenXML distance, size units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194403/openxml-distance-size-units/71379611#71379611)

Comment: This reply is quite late, I will check this next time I need this. Thank you, looks useful.